# Showing that $ { }_2F_1(1, n + 1;n+2; \frac{1}{2}) \in O(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

Is the following statement true?
$$ { }_2F_1\left(1, n + 1;n+2; \frac{1}{2}\right) \in O(2^n)$$

What are the steps to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply plugging the arguments into the definition of the hypergeometric function shows that
$$
{}_2F_1\big( 1,n+1;n+2;\tfrac12 \big) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^j(n+1+j)} < \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{2^j} = 2.
$$
In fact it is an increasing function of $n$ that tends to $2$ from below as $n$ tends to infinity.

So your statement is true (assuming you mean for $n$ to stay rather larger than $-2$) but much weaker than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By way of "enrichment" we can obtain the formula for the hypergeometric value using the Barnes integral. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) we have the following integral:
$$_2F_1(a,b;c; z) =
\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}
\times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty} 
\frac{\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(b+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(c+s)} (-z)^s ds.$$
Subsituting the values for $a,b$ and $c$ we get
$$_2F_1(1,n+1;n+2; 1/2) \\=
\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(n+1)}
\times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty} 
\frac{\Gamma(1+s)\Gamma(n+1+s)\Gamma(-s)}{\Gamma(n+2+s)} (-1/2)^s ds
\\ = - (n+1)\times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}
\times \frac{1}{1+n+s} (1/2)^s e^{\pi i s} ds.$$
Evaluating this in the right half plane with the Cauchy Residue Theorem we get
$$(n+1)\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \times \frac{1}{n+1+q} (1/2)^q e^{i\pi q}.
 = (n+1) \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{n+1+q} (1/2)^q.$$
This gives the asymptotic expansion
$$\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{1+q/(n+1)} (1/2)^q
\\ \sim \sum_{q\ge 0} (1/2)^q
- \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{q\ge 0} q(1/2)^q
+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{q\ge 0} q^2(1/2)^q
- \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\sum_{q\ge 0} q^3(1/2)^q
+\cdots$$
which is
$$2  - \frac{2}{n+1} + \frac{6}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{26}{(n+1)^3} +\cdots$$
confirming the result from the definitive answer.

**Remark.** The above is definitely an asymptotic expansion and not a convergent series. Care must be taken when using it for calculations. The rule is to take as many initial terms as possible before they start diverging. E.g. for $n=25$ the first nine / ten terms give $$1.930731710\quad\text{and}\quad 1.930733159$$ whereas the exact value is
$$1.930732621 .$$

**Digression.**
The reason that this is an asymptotic expansion as opposed to a convergent series lies in the fact that $$\sum_{q\ge 0} q^n (1/2)^q = \mathrm{Li}_{-n}(1/2)
\sim \frac{n!}{(\log 2)^{n+1}},$$
so that the coefficients outgrow any polynomial in $n$ as documented for example at the [OEIS entry A076726](https://oeis.org/A076726). (In what follows the $n$ is not the same as in the first part of this post.)

We now prove this as it is a calculation worth knowing. Start with
$$\mathrm{Li}_{-n}(z) = 
\sum_{k=0}^k k! {n+1 \brace k+1} \left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^{k+1}$$
and note that for $z=1/2$ the rational power disappears so that
$$\mathrm{Li}_{-n}(1/2) = \sum_{k=0}^n k! {n+1 \brace k+1}.$$
Now the bivariate mixed generating function of the Stirling numbers of the second kind is
$$\exp(u(\exp(z)-1))$$ so that
$${n+1\brace k+1} = (n+1)! [z^{n+1}] [u^{k+1}] \exp(u(\exp(z)-1))
=  (n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.$$
Returning to the sum we get
$$(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$
We may extend the sum to infinity as the extra terms do not contribute to $[z^{n+1}]$ to get $$(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}
\\= (n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \log \frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)}
= (n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \log \frac{1}{2-\exp(z)}
= (n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \left(\log \frac{1}{2} + \log \frac{1}{1-\exp(z)/2}\right).$$
Therefore we seek the asymptotics of the following term:
$$(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \log \frac{1}{1-\exp(z)/2}.$$
This has branch points at $\rho_m = \log 2 + 2\pi i m,$ with $m$ an integer. The one that is closest to the origin is $\rho_0 = \log 2,$ so we seek an expansion about this point.

We observe that the pole of the inner term is simple as we compute the residue:
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1-\exp(z)/2}; z=\log 2\right)
=\left. \frac{1}{-\exp(z)/2}\right|_{z=\log 2} = -1.$$
Now considering the Laurent expansion of the inner term the simple pole dominates in a neighborhood of $\log 2$ while the higher order terms vanish, giving 
$$\log \left(-\frac{1}{z-\log 2}\right)
= \log\left(\frac{1}{\log 2 - z}\right)
= \log\frac{1}{\log 2}+ \log\left(\frac{1}{1-z/\log 2}\right).$$
We therefore get the following asymptotics
$$(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \log\left(\frac{1}{1-z/\log 2}\right)
= (n+1)! \frac{(1/\log 2)^{n+1}}{n+1} 
= \frac{n!}{(\log 2)^{n+1}}$$
as was to be shown.

Replacing $n$ by $q$ and returning to the initial computation we get for the asymptotics of the term with index $q$ the formula
$$(-1)^q \frac{q!}{(\log 2)^{q+1}\times (n+1)^q}$$
which is now clearly seen to eventually diverge.